# JSOUP to parse text/images

Tags: java, android, json

I am using Java and would like to download the names of [celebrities](http://www.posh24.com/celebrities) to my labels/textviews and then download the image to imageView.

How can I do this with JSOUP? I tried searching, but always something with javascript, not my goal?